# How do i return 0 as decimal value as default if there are not data in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
workedHours = db.WorkedHours.
                 Where(wh => wh.EmployeeId == ID).
                 Sum(h => h.DayHours)
```

this part of the query may or may not have data and

```
db.WorkedHours.Where(wh => wh.EmployeeId == ID)
```

I am trying to `Sum`.How do I return 0 in case there are no data to do sum?

Comment: The default should be 0, what do you get now?

Comment: workedHours = db.WorkedHours.Where(wh => wh.EmployeeId == ID).Select(h => h.DayHours) .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(); This solved the issue. Thank you for reaching out. How do I close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = db.WorkedHours
    .Where(wh => wh.EmployeeId == ID)
    .Select(h => h.DayHours)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Sum();
```